# ListView does not highlight on programmatic setSelection

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

**Please** distinguish that my ListView does highlight when a user clicks on an Item. The problem is when the user first opens my Activity, I want to preselect an item so I use `listView.setSelection(position)`. But doing this does not cause the view to highlight. Now I understand the documentation for setSelection says

> If in touch mode, the item will not be selected...

What I am looking for is a workaround to that particular problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can change choice mode to :

```
Listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)
```

and you can set selection color aswell :

```
Listview.setSelector(android.R.color.darker_gray);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. But unfortunately your particular answer is why I have **Please** in bold. You are offering to solve the problem that the post specifically says is not the problem. But thanks for trying to help.